# Взять битмап пикчербокса

Tags: c#

У меня есть условный рисунок внутри пикчербокс1, надо его вынести в пикчербокс2. В русскоязычном интернете не нашел.

```
Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
Graphics gg = pictureBox2.CreateGraphics();
g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), 0, 0, 10, 10);
gg = g;
```

---

Я не нашел как это сделать, есть только одно обсуждение: [How to save a picturebox control as a jpeg file after it's edited](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1063505/4827341). Но они так и не нашли ответ.... Единственное решение это рисовать сразу в битмап, а потом присваивать его.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В заголовке у вас написано "битмап". Bitmap - это *растровое* изображение.
В коде у вас *векторные* команды рисования на Graphics.

Так что именно вам нужно?

---

Если нужен битмап, создавайте объект типа `Bitmap` и рисуйте на его графиксе. Потом это растровое изображение можно присваивать свойству `(Background)Image` любого контрола. Можно и в файл сохранять.

---

Кроме того, если просто рисовать на графиксе, созданном у контрола вызовом метода `CreateGraphics()`, то рисунок будет исчезать, например, после сворачивания-разворачивания формы. Чтобы рисунок оставался, нужно рисовать в событии `Paint`.

---

Если вам нужно работать именно с векторной графикой, создайте отдельный метод для отрисовки. Наподобие:

```
private void Draw(Graphics graphics)
{
    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
    {
        graphics.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание на использование `using` - кисть является ресурсом, который нужно освобождать. Это важно!

Теперь этот метод можно использовать для рисования на любых контролах:

```
Draw(pictureBox1.CreateGraphics());
Draw(pictureBox2.CreateGraphics());
```

---

Как уже было сказано, рисовать нужно в событии Paint. Используем этот метод в нём:

```
private void PictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Draw(e.Graphics);
}
```

На это событие можно подписать любой пикчабокс (и вообще контрол).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте через `Bitmap`:

```
Bitmap img_bitmap = new Bitmap(PaintPictureBox.Image);
PaintPictureBox.Image = img_bitmap;
```

Comment: В вашем случае:                   
Bitmap img_bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
pictureBox2.Image = img_bitmap;

Comment: Нарисованное на графиксе не заносится автоматически в Image.